# Как мне поступить со списком (list)?

Tags: python, list

Есть список:

```
>>>>list = ["tra-ta-ta'123456'list-temp_bla-bla-bla.12","pam-param'list_temp:opa'7'","templa'list_tempte-0'23_.sr"]
```

Каким методом и собственно вообще, как мне выполнить следующее: удалить определенный элемент(`'list_temp`) и привести элементы списка, так чтобы они начинались с новой строки, добавить `'\n'`, чтобы выглядело следующим образом:

```
>>>>print list  
.."tra-ta-ta'123456_bla-bla-bla.12"  
.."pam-param:opa'7'"  
.."template-0'23_.sr"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое не по теме, не называйте переменную как list - это зарезервированое слово языка, думаю не стоит объяснять почему это плохо. Принт можете сделать через join:

```
print "\n".join(list_name)
```

По поводу удаления, не совсем понятно, хотите вы удалить какойто текст, в конкретном элементе, или элемент с этим текстом. Если хотите удалить текст, можете воспользоваться replace из string, если элемент - list_name.pop() - думаю сможете прочитать о его применение.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = ["tra-ta-ta'123456'list-temp_bla-bla-bla.12","pam-param'list_temp:opa'7'","templa'list_tempte-0'23_.sr"]
def action(string):
    string = string.replace("'list_temp","")
    return string + '\n'
list = map(action,list)
    print list
["tra-ta-ta'123456'list-temp_bla-bla-bla.12\n", "pam-param:opa'7'\n", "template-0'23_.sr\n"]
```

Насколько я помню print не может вывести список так как вы хотите.

Comment: можно 

    for i in list:

 print i
но тогда '\n' ни к чему.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_ = ["tra-ta-ta'123456'list-temp_bla-bla-bla.12", 
         "pam-param'list_temp:opa'7'",
         "templa'list_tempte-0'23_.sr"]
```

(Обратите внимание на замену `list` на `list_` - это обыкновенная практика для зарезервированных слов языка.)

```
remove1 = "'list-temp"           # для -
remove2 = "'list_temp"           # для _

new_list = []
for elem in list_:
    elem = elem.replace(remove1, "")
    elem = elem.replace(remove2, "")
    elem += "\n"
    new_list.append(elem)
```

В цикле удаляется как `'list-temp`, так и `'list_temp`, добавляется `\n` и затем результат добавляется в новый список `new_list`.